# WordPress/ Woo commerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a project called which sells sarees ( An Indian dress ). the problem I faced is the customer wants to save her body dimensions{they have more than one value}  in the account so when she buys a saree we can send the blouse with her sizes.

So is there any plugin [ paid / Free ] where I can add a new tab in my account area like my dimensions so the user can add her dimension there and save.

Comment: check this https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: you can add the products options for that when user can easily pick there sizes and add to cart

Answer (score 0):

here are some plugins or links which will help you regarding this

https://wordpress.org/plugins/productsize-chart-for-woocommerce/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-product-size-charts-for-woocommerce/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-size-charts-for-woocommerce/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/
https://www.artsygeek.com/adding-sizes-to-products-in-woocommerce/

Thanks